# A question on hom functor of divisible groups

Tags: group-theory, modules

I'm having a trouble with these problems:

For $D$ is an  divisible group and $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers prove that

$Hom(D,\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $Hom(D,\mathbb{Z_n})=0$ for any divisible group $D$.

Comment: OK: what are the troubles? How can we help you?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: homomorphic images of divisible groups are divisible.

Comment: Could you give me  more hints? I can't used  that hint!

Comment: @MinhNam Subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic.

Comment: @MinhNam If you know what a divisible group is, you should be able to prove that if $D$ is divisible and $f\colon D\to G$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups, then $f(D)$ is a divisibile subgroup of $G$. What are the divisible subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$? And of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?